# Datatable Archival SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a database that is 54 GB in size, some of the tables have loads of rows in them.

Now querying these tables eats up performance and it takes ages for queries to execute.

Have created indexes and stuff, but now I am planning to archive records in certain tables and only query them when user wants to.

For example, let's say I have a table called `Transaction` and I often don't need rows of older than 3 months.

Now what I want to do is store all the rows of the `Transaction` table which are more than 3 months old into some other table and query that table only when user in UI says view archived transactions.

Options I can think of:

1. Creating `ArchivedTransaction` in the same database, but problem is that size of database will keep growing and at some point I will have to start deleting rows.
2. Moving rows to different database altogether but in this case how do I manage database request, there will be lot of change required, also not sure of performance when some one says view archived rows
3. Adding a column Archived to tables and then checking for the flag when needed, but size issue still the same and performance doesn't improve to that extent.

I am not sure which way to go, I am sure there is much better way to handle this that I am not aware of.

Any ideas which way to go? is there some way you can suggest.

Comment: I wasn't referring to you, Pranali your inline code was fine, I was referring to [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1945256) which contained some invalid formatting which I've manually removed.

Comment: If your edition supports it, [Partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190787.aspx) would be an option to consider. And if you want the ability to easily be able to access archived data as well as current data, keeping them in the same DB seems sensible. I don't see an issue with database size. 54GB is nowhere near the limits of the product. If it's a file size issue, you should be looking at using multiple File Groups.